# how to style CSS for Js daterangepicker after start date and end date is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, daterangepicker

I want to style my `DateRangePicker` in a way that once I have selected the `start-date` and `end-date` then all the `<td>` tag between these two dates are styled with

```
background-color:red
```

**Problem:**
I only want to style all `<td>` tag once I have selected **start-date** and **end-date**.

When I select the `start-date` I get the classes available, active and `start-date`.
When I select the `end-date` I get the classes available, active and `end-date`.
all the `<td>` in between have classes `.available`, `.in-range`

if I style using classes `.start-date`, `.in-range` and `.end-date`
it change the `background-color` when I hover over `<td>` after selecting start date because it gets the class `.in-range` while hovering.

```
<tr>
  <td class="weekend available" data-title="r1c0">5</td>
  <td class="active start-date available" data-title="r1c1">6</td>
  <td class="in-range available" data-title="r1c2">7</td>
  <td class="in-range available" data-title="r1c3">8</td>
  <td class="in-range available" data-title="r1c4">9</td>
  <td class="in-range available" data-title="r1c5">10</td>
  <td class="weekend in-range available" data-title="r1c6">11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="weekend in-range available" data-title="r2c0">12</td>
  <td class="in-range available" data-title="r2c1">13</td>
  <td class="in-range available" data-title="r2c2">14</td>
  <td class="active end-date in-range available" data-title="r2c3">15</td>
  <td class="available" data-title="r2c4">16</td>
  <td class="available" data-title="r2c5">17</td>
  <td class="weekend available" data-title="r2c6">18</td>
</tr>
```

This is the code for when I have selected the start date as 6 and end-date as 15.

I can not style like:

```
.start-date, .in-range, .end-date{
    background-color: "red";
}
```

because by default after selecting start date when I hover over other dates it gets the class `.in-range`.

How can I style it using `css`, `js` or `jquery`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do. If you can create a simple example in codesandbox or codepen it might be easier to help.

Comment: Why is it getting the .in-range class when you hover over it? is it something in your code or from the pluggin itself?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I am using daterangepicker from http://www.daterangepicker.com/ and some how its a functionality that if this dates comes after my start date and I go through it then it adds the in-range class in this element.

Comment: Hi Will, I just want to change the background color of the all the dates from start date till end date but after i have selected the end date. If i want to use css .start-date, .in-range, .end-date. then it will change also the css for dates in-range before i have not selected the end-date. Because as i hover through it, it gets the "in-range" class. I am using the plugin "daterangepicker" from http://www.daterangepicker.com/.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I hope three years later it is not too late ;-)

```
.daterangepicker td.in-range {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #a12727;
}
```